# PHP not recognize as a command using windows command-line

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
C:\>php tools\spark install -v1.0.0 example-spark
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why is this so? What are the things I need to do for me to execute this command? Please help. Thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change my environment variables in the `control panel->perfromance and maintenance->system->advance and click environment variables and edit the path to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add PHP to your Windows PATH variable.  You can read a good explanation of how to do this [in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html
but use your php directory instead